# How do I org.bluetooth.characteristic.report_map for more than one type of report?

Tags: usb, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, hid, bluez

Alright, I'm building a keyboard with an integrated touch-screen used as a mouse, I'm sending the data generated over BLE via HID OVER GATT. This works fine for org.bluetooth.characteristic.boot_keyboard_input_report & org.bluetooth.characteristic.boot_mouse_input_report, but I'm not very certain how to configure the report_map and what I need to send according to these declarations.

The Main question is really, because there is no hybrid type of Usage, I need to use two Usage. But do I need a second Usage Page? How do you define the Collection (Application) for such a hybrid device?

```
Usage Page
Usage Keyboard
??Usage Page
Usage Mouse
```

So I defined my report_map like this:

```
   0x05, 0x01, // Usage Page (Generic Desktop),
    0x09, 0x06, // Usage (Keyboard),
    0xA1, 0x01, // Collection (Application),
        0x05, 0x07, // Usage Page (Key Codes);
        0x19, 0xE0, // Usage Minimum (224),
        0x29, 0xE7, // Usage Maximum (231),
        0x15, 0x00, // Logical Minimum (0),
        0x25, 0x01, // Logical Maximum (1),
        0x75, 0x01, // Report Size (1),
        0x95, 0x08, // Report Count (8),
        0x81, 0x02, // Input (Data, Variable, Absolute),            ; Modifier-Byte 8 bit
        0x95, 0x01, // Report Count (1),
        0x75, 0x08, // Report Size (8),
        0x81, 0x01, // Input (Constant),                            ; Reserved byte 8 bit
        0x95, 0x05, // Report Count (5),
        0x75, 0x01, // Report Size (1),
        0x05, 0x08, // Usage Page (Page# for LEDs),                
        0x19, 0x01, // Usage Minimum (1),
        0x29, 0x05, // Usage Maximum (5),
        0x91, 0x02, // Output (Data, Variable, Absolute),           ; LED byte 5 bits
        0x95, 0x01, // Report Count (1),
        0x75, 0x03, // Report Size (3),
        0x91, 0x01, // Output (Constant),                           ; Padding of 3 bits
        0x95, 0x06, // Report Count (6),
        0x75, 0x08, // Report Size (8),
        0x15, 0x00, // Logical Minimum (0),
        0x25, 0x65, // Logical Maximum(101),
        0x05, 0x07, // Usage Page (Key Codes), 
        0x19, 0x00, // Usage Minimum (0),
        0x29, 0x65, // Usage Maximum (101),
        0x81, 0x00, // Input (Data, Array),
    0xC0, // End Collection    
    0x05, 0x01, // USAGE_PAGE (Generic Desktop)
    0x09, 0x02, // USAGE (Mouse)
    0xa1, 0x01, // COLLECTION (Application)
    0x09, 0x02, // USAGE (Mouse)
    0xa1, 0x02, // COLLECTION (Logical)
    0x09, 0x01, // USAGE (Pointer)
    0xa1, 0x00, // COLLECTION (Physical)
    // ------------------------------ Buttons
    0x05, 0x09, // USAGE_PAGE (Button) 
    0x19, 0x01, // USAGE_MINIMUM (Button 1)
    0x29, 0x05, // USAGE_MAXIMUM (Button 5)
    0x15, 0x00, // LOGICAL_MINIMUM (0)
    0x25, 0x01, // LOGICAL_MAXIMUM (1)
    0x75, 0x01, // REPORT_SIZE (1)
    0x95, 0x03, // REPORT_COUNT (3)
    0x81, 0x02, // INPUT (Data,Var,Abs)
    // ------------------------------ Padding
    0x75, 0x05, // REPORT_SIZE (5)
    0x95, 0x01, // REPORT_COUNT (1)
    0x81, 0x03, // INPUT (Cnst,Var,Abs)
    // ------------------------------ X,Y position
    0x05, 0x01, // USAGE_PAGE (Generic Desktop)
    0x09, 0x30, // USAGE (X)
    0x09, 0x31, // USAGE (Y)
    0x15, 0x81, // LOGICAL_MINIMUM (-127)
    0x25, 0x7f, // LOGICAL_MAXIMUM (127)
    0x75, 0x08, // REPORT_SIZE (8)
    0x95, 0x02, // REPORT_COUNT (2)
    0x81, 0x06, // INPUT (Data,Var,Rel)
    0xa1, 0x02, // COLLECTION (Logical)
    // ------------------------------ Vertical wheel res multiplier
    0x09, 0x48, // USAGE (Resolution Multiplier)
    0x15, 0x00, // LOGICAL_MINIMUM (0)
    0x25, 0x01, // LOGICAL_MAXIMUM (1)
    0x35, 0x01, // PHYSICAL_MINIMUM (1)
    0x45, 0x04, // PHYSICAL_MAXIMUM (4)
    0x75, 0x02, // REPORT_SIZE (2)
    0x95, 0x01, // REPORT_COUNT (1)
    0xa4, // PUSH
    0xb1, 0x02, // FEATURE (Data,Var,Abs)
    // ------------------------------ Vertical wheel
    0x09, 0x38, // USAGE (Wheel)
    0x15, 0x81, // LOGICAL_MINIMUM (-127)
    0x25, 0x7f, // LOGICAL_MAXIMUM (127)
    0x35, 0x00, // PHYSICAL_MINIMUM (0) - reset physical
    0x45, 0x00, // PHYSICAL_MAXIMUM (0)
    0x75, 0x08, // REPORT_SIZE (8)
    0x81, 0x06, // INPUT (Data,Var,Rel)
    0xc0, // END_COLLECTION
    0xa1, 0x02, // COLLECTION (Logical)
    // ------------------------------ Horizontal wheel res multiplier
    0x09, 0x48, // USAGE (Resolution Multiplier)
    0xb4, // POP
    0xb1, 0x02, // FEATURE (Data,Var,Abs)
    // ------------------------------ Padding for Feature report
    0x35, 0x00, // PHYSICAL_MINIMUM (0) - reset physical
    0x45, 0x00, // PHYSICAL_MAXIMUM (0)
    0x75, 0x04, // REPORT_SIZE (4)
    0xb1, 0x03, // FEATURE (Cnst,Var,Abs)
    // ------------------------------ Horizontal wheel
    0x05, 0x0c, // USAGE_PAGE (Consumer Devices)
    0x0a, 0x38, 0x02, // USAGE (AC Pan)
    0x15, 0x81, // LOGICAL_MINIMUM (-127)
    0x25, 0x7f, // LOGICAL_MAXIMUM (127)
    0x75, 0x08, // REPORT_SIZE (8)
    0x81, 0x06, // INPUT (Data,Var,Rel)
    0xc0, // END_COLLECTION
    0xc0, // END_COLLECTION
    0xc0, // END_COLLECTION
    0xc0 // END_COLLECTION
```

I'm not entirely sure, if I am allowed to define two Usage Pages, or if I need to create a collection and but all of the reports in there.

The second thing I'm not sure of, is how I create the values for specific INPUT Reports. Do they have some numbering system via report-id's that I don't get? Or do they have to be send all at once (I'm guessing this is right).

In my case the reports would look like this:

```
// Output Report
// 
// Byte | D7            D6              D5              D4          D3              D2              D1          D0
// ------+---------------------------------------------------------------------
// 0    | NUM_LOCK      CAPS_LOCK       SCROLL_LOCK     COMPOSE     KANA            CONSTANT        CONSTANT    CONSTANT

// Input Report for Keyboard
// Byte | D7            D6              D5          D4          D3              D2              D1          D0
// ------+---------------------------------------------------------------------
// 0    | LEFT_CTRL     LEFT_SHIFT      LEFT_ALT    LEFT_OS     RIGHT_CTRL      RIGHT_SHIFT     RIGHT_ALT   RIGHT_OS
// 1    | Reserved please leave at 0
// 2-7  | Keycodes

// Input Report for Pointer
// Byte | D7 D6 D5 D4 D3 D2 D1 D0
// ------+---------------------------------------------------------------------
// 0 | 0 0 0 Forward Back Middle Right Left (Button)
// 1 | X
// 2 | Y
// 3 | Vertical Wheel
// 4 | Horizontal (Tilt) Wheel
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might want to tag this with the system you're using...  such an ios' core bluetooth, Android bluetooth, linux bluez, or whatever Windows uses.

Comment: It's not related to any of the systems mentioned, since the underlying bluetooth data is related only to the USB HID Specification, the USB HID Usage Table and of corse the Bluetooth specification of the HID Service and the HID over GATT specification... but it doesn't really have anything to do with ios, android or bluez.... but I'll tag it anyways, maybe it'll attract the right kind of people