# How do you add Characteristics using BluetoothLeAdvertiser?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-5.0-lollipop, android-bluetooth

Upon inspection of the Android BluetoothLE Peripheral API I was wondering how you could do the following things?

- How do you add Characterisitics (with Permissions like Notify, Read, Write,...)
- How do you react to write requests?
- How do you detect reads of your data?
- Can you handle the subscription of characteristics?
- How do you send updates to a central that subscribed to one of your characterisitics?
- Why has google not given out any extensive documentation of these features?

Comment: Read BLE callbacks from Android developers site.

Comment: @jitainsharma so It is possible to retrieve notifications?

Comment: Yes, possible with BluetoothGattCallback, LeScanCallback for BLE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for Bluetooth Gatt Server role, BluetoothLeAdvertiser can not include characteristics. read for [BluetoothGattServer Android](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattServer.html)

also tried answering all of your questions.

- **How do you add Characteristics (with Permissions like Notify, Read,
  Write,...)**

You do not add characteristics directly, you have to add characteristic into Service, you can give above permissions(read,write,notify) to chars. read this [BluetoothGattCharacteristic](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCharacteristic.html)

- **How do you react to write requests?**

you gets your callback method(onWriteRequest something) called by system, then you change your data and you should call [sendResponse](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattServer.html#sendResponse%28android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20byte%5B%5D%29) method, read the link.

- **How do you detect reads of your data?**

onReadRequest method gets called by system. read about gatt server callbacks on the android docs(link shared already)

- **Can you handle the subscription of characteristics?**

Yes, You can. add chars into service, register them with gattServer(read above), and if monitor role asks for notification registration, you send notification, each time your data changes.

- **How do you send updates to a central that subscribed to one of your characterisitics?**

you call [notifyCharacteristicChanged](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattServer.html#notifyCharacteristicChanged%28android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice,%20android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic,%20boolean%29)

- **Why has google not given out any extensive documentation of these features?**

BLE is new, android is still struggling to have stable solution first, no comments on why Google not given.

Comment: is this using the Bluetooth Peripheral Role? This is not explicitly said within the documentation. But it makes a hole lot more sense, because the functionality is what should be expected of a Bluetooth Device being in the Peripheral Role

Comment: Obviously, GattServer is for peripheral/Reporter/Server role. though you can also have peripheral and central role on the same device.
It depends on the implementation. Let me know if you need anything more? 
@S.vanWickern you can also accept or upvote the answer :)

Comment: Sorry I forgot to accept. But your answer is obviously correct and deserves the credit.

Comment: Cool, Thanks, You can ping me anytime for BLE on Android related issues.

Comment: Maybe you know this one too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29263077/how-do-i-org-bluetooth-characteristic-report-map-for-more-than-one-type-of-repor

Comment: HOGP is not my cup of tea, Sorry.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73952/discussion-between-s-van-wickern-and-androidgeek).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73962/discussion-between-s-van-wickern-and-aankit).